# php redirect after form action dropzonejs

Tags: php, redirect

Hi I have the below form in index.php

```
  <form action="file1.php?arg=<?php echo $id ?>"
    class="dropzone"
    id="my-awesome-dropzone">
  </form>
```

Also in the index.php I have

```
  if ( !isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || $_SESSION['logged-in'] !== true) {
    header('Location: file.php');
    exit;
  }
```

The file1.php is as follows

```
  $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
  $storeFolder = 'dir'.$id;   //2
  if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3              
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
  }
```

How to redirect after move_uploaded_file is completed to mytest.php file?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
$storeFolder = 'dir'.$id;   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3              
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5
    $status = move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

    if($status){ // If it return's true on SUCCESS
        header('Location: mytest.php');
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the uploaded file being moved?